# How to find non-cyclic subgroups of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to find all of the subgroups of a given group. To do this, I follow the following steps:

1. Look at the order of the group. For example, if it is $15$, the subgroups can only be of order $1,3,5,15$.
2. Then find the cyclic groups.
3. Then find the non cyclic groups.

But i do not know how to find the non cyclic groups. For example, let us consider the dihedral group $D_4$, then the subgroups are of the orders $1,2,4$ or $8$. I find all cyclic groups. Then, I saw that there are non-cyclic groups of order $4$. How can I find them? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, finding the subgroups (of a biggish group) won't be easy.

In the case of $D_4$, the only non-cyclic groups besides $D_4$ itself can only be of order $4$. So you are looking at subgroups of $G$ that consist of the identity, and three involutions (elements of order $2$) $a, b, c = ab$.

Now try out the various possibilities, avoiding repetitions.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i had been wondering. So, let us say  D4={e,p1,p2,p3,s1,s2,u1,u2} and {e,u1},{e,u2},{e,p2},{e,s1},{e,s2},{e,p1,p2,p3} are cyclic subgroups. Since there are 5 subgroups of order 2, i have to try all 3 combinations, which is 5 choose 3 =10 possibilities, right?

Comment: @bigO you can save some work by noting that if you multiply together two reflections (which are $s_1,s_2,u_1,u_2$ in your notation, and have all order $2$) you will get a rotation. Now  there is only one rotation of order $2$ (which should be $p_2$ in your notation), so you don't have to try all possibilities!

Comment: Thanks, but how do we know that if we multiply two reflections we will get a rotation?

Comment: @bigO, the rotations form a subgroup $N$ of index $2$ of $G = D_4$, and the reflections are the other coset, that is, if $r$ is any reflection, then $r N$ is the set of reflections. Now if $r, s$ are two reflections, then since $G/N$ has order $2$, we have $N = rN \cdot sN = rs N$, so the product $rs$ is in $N$. Informally, think of the square with the up side painted white, and the down side painted black. A rotation will leave the white side up, while a reflection will exchange the two sides. If you compose two reflections, you end up with the white side up, so you have done a rotation.

Answer (score 3):

In the $n=15=3\cdot 5$ case, recall that every group of order $p$ prime is cyclic. This leaves you with the subgroups of order $15$. How many are there?

Of course, this is not as easy in general. For general finite groups, the classification is a piece of work. Finite Abelian groups are easier, as they fall in the classification of [finitely-generated Abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group).

Now, $D_4$ is not that bad. The only nontrivial thing is to find all the subgroups of order $4$. Cyclic ones correspond to order $4$ elements in $D_4$. Noncyclic ones are of the form $\{\pm 1,\pm z\}$ where $z$ is an order $2$ element in $D_4$. Since $D_4$ has eight elements, it is fairly easy to determine all these order $2$ and $4$ elements.

Comment: And what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Well, OK, it does have a lot to do with the first example, but the question was more general (there was also the example of $D_4$).  So I think this is more of a comment than an answer.  Then again, so is mine really.

Comment: @TaraB  Given the observation 1), this means that the subgroups of order $3$ and $5$ are cyclic. This only leaves the subgroups of $G$ of order $15$... How many are there?

Comment: Yes, sure, _in that particular case_.  Anyway, I have no problem with the edited version, although some help with what to do in general is what the OP is really looking for.

Comment: @julien: You killed the poor $D_4$ at last. Nice +

Comment: @BabakS. I had no choice, I was forced to! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can try is find the groups of each order. A group of order $2$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which contains identity and another element of order $2$. How many elements of order $2$ are there?

For groups of order $4$, they are isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. In $\mathbb{Z}_4$, it contains an element of order $4$, so what is it? The other case is similar.

You can also find them using [Group Explorer](http://groupexplorer.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

For any two subgroups $U,V \leq G$ there is a unique smallest subgroup $\langle U,V \rangle$ above $U$ and $V$. It consists of all finite products of elements of $U$ and $V$. You can gain all subgroups of $G$ by starting with the cyclic subgroups and iterating that operation until no new group occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You could always start by taking the generators of two of your cyclic subgroups and see if they generate something you don't already have.

Comment: What do you mean by see if they generate something you dont already have? So, for example if we think about D4, I have 5 cyclic subgroups of order 2, and 1 cyclic subgroup of order 4. Let them be {e,u1},{e,u2},{e,p2},{e,s1},{e,s2},{e,p1,p2,p3}. And let D4={e,p1,p2,p3,s1,s2,u1,u2}. What should i do after this step?

Comment: Well, you don't so much want to 'let' them be some abstract set of letters as to see which elements they _actually_ contain.  Then you can see what you get when you multiply elements from different subgroups together.

Answer (score -1):

This statement might help you 
" for every subgroup of dihedral group ,either every member of the subgroup is a rotation or exactly half of the members are rotations "