# Finding all the subgroups of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need a method to find all subgroups from any finite group. For example, the subgroups of $D_4 $ (of order $4$): $\{(1), (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4), (1 \ 3)(2 \ 4), (1 \ 4 \ 3 \ 2)\}$.

Okay, I can understand this but the others .. how we can get them? Is there any theorem or something?

Comment: Your group "$D_4$" appears to be $S_4.$ The group $S_4$ has $4!=24$ elements, while $D_4$ has $8$ or $16$ (depending on which version of dihedral notation is being used).

Comment: @CameronBuie: I think that you've rushed a bit. The OP asks for a *general* algorithm for finding all the subgroups of *any* finite given group. $D_4$ is not central to his question. Could you please reconsider your close vote?

Comment: @AlexM.: I'm aware. I outline a general algorithm in my answer there, though it happens to coincide with finding all subgroups of $D_4.$

Comment: Then there's [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/332060/28900) and [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/892840/28900), too.